# android Xposed Module

Tags: android, xposed

I'm trying to develop Appliction that use Xposed Module.
In my project I take samples off Apps runing on the device I can choose which Apps.
In the Xposed Module I can see if one of my Apps is started by a common list, and I don't successed to start my sampling class because I don't have a context. I tried to do it through FileObserver (the Module writing to a file that the FileObserver observe) from boot service and still on the onEvent func in the FileObserver I don`t have a context too and I don't know how can I start my sample class...
Any solution Please?

Answer (score 0):

If you require the context within your Xposed application check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059264/how-to-get-context-through-hooking-in-android/28635776#28635776).

If you require the context from an application you are hooking, then a nice trick is to intercept the launching of new Activities in the application (Activities extend Context). e.g.:

```
Class<?> instrumentation = XposedHelpers.findClass(
                "android.app.Instrumentation", lpparam.classLoader);

XposedBridge.hookAllMethods(instrumentation, "newActivity", new XC_MethodHook() {

                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

                    mCurrentActivity = (Activity) param.getResult();

                    Log.v(TAG, "Current Activity : " + mCurrentActivity.getClass().getName());

                    Context ctx = (Context) mCurrentActivity;
                }
});
```

Good luck!